# Increment behavior on strings - PHP easter egg?

Tags: php, types, increment

```
$var = 'test_1';
var_dump(++$var); // string(6) "test_2" 

$var2 = '1_test';
var_dump(++$var2); // string(6) "1_tesu"

$var3 = 'test_z';
var_dump(++$var3); // string(6) "test_a"

$var4 = 'test_';
var_dump(++$var4); // string(5) "test_"
```

So apparently, using an increment operator on a string has the effect of increasing the digit if the last character is a number, increasing the letter and then resetting to a once z if the last character is in the alphabet, and has no effect on non alpha numeric characters.

Is this a standard feature, expected in many scripting languages, or did I just find a PHP easter egg?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.operators.increment.php#74639

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations
>   on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a =
>   'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into
>   '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that
>   character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so
>   only plain ASCII characters (a-z and A-Z) are supported.
>   Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the
>   original string is unchanged.

-> http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is vague and not well written in this area :( For instance, it does not cover the case of `++"_1"` -> `"_2"` and, either the documentation is *wrong* about what `"_Z"++` turns into.

Comment: About the documentation being horrid: compare `"_Z"++` with `"Z++"` :-)

Comment: At least `"Z++"` is very obvious just a "Z" and two "+" in a string. Nothing magic here :)

Comment: @KingCrunch Heh, oops. `"Z"++` even ;-)

Comment: Curious ... both doesn't work in my interactive shell (`php -a`) saying "unespected T_INC" ... Ah, I see: Doesn't work for constants, only for variables ^^ Never used, never noticed. Now I know.

Comment: @KingCrunch I am shortening the examples: it makes no sense for constants; read `"Z"++` as `$a = "Z"; $a++`

Answer (score 2):

Its officially documentated http://php.net/language.operators.increment

Answer (score 0):

It's not an Easter egg. It's expected in PHP, but no it's not common in other languages. (At least not incrementing letters.) PHP treats strings containing a number the same as numbers in most cases. So you can also `"2" * "2"` for example.

Comment: The example is different case than the post. It would indicate that `"test"++` would be similar to `"test" + 1`, which indeed is *not* going on. The `++` behavior is "special" while the `x+y` behavior is juts an implicit conversion.

Comment: Good point. I actually considered the specific point about numbers as an addendum to my first statement. But read as a whole, you're right that it isn't clear.