# PHP Echo char variable mistake

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php
for($i="a";$i<="z";$i++)    {
echo $i;
}
?>
```

I have a question that if

```
$i <="y"
```

it's still correct and echo

```
a->y
```

But if 
`$i<="z"` like above the result will be :

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaaabacadaeafagahaiajakalamanaoapaqarasatauavawaxayazbabbbcbdbebfbgbhbibjbkblbmbnbobpbqbrbsbtbubvbwbxbybzcacbcccdcecfcgchcicjckclcmcncocpcqcrcsctcucvcwcxcyczdadbdcdddedfdgdhdidjdkdldmdndodpdqdrdsdtdudvdwdxdydzeaebecedeeefegeheiejekelemeneoepeqereseteuevewexeyezfafbfcfdfefffgfhfifjfkflfmfnfofpfqfrfsftfufvfwfxfyfzgagbgcgdgegfggghgigjgkglgmgngogpgqgrgsgtgugvgwgxgygzhahbhchdhehfhghhhihjhkhlhmhnhohphqhrhshthuhvhwhxhyhziaibicidieifigihiiijikiliminioipiqirisitiuiviwixiyizjajbjcjdjejfjgjhjijjjkjljmjnjojpjqjrjsjtjujvjwjxjyjzkakbkckdkekfkgkhkikjkkklkmknkokpkqkrksktkukvkwkxkykzlalblcldlelflglhliljlklllmlnlolplqlrlsltlulvlwlxlylzmambmcmdmemfmgmhmimjmkmlmmmnmompmqmrmsmtmumvmwmxmymznanbncndnenfngnhninjnknlnmnnnonpnqnrnsntnunvnwnxnynzoaobocodoeofogohoiojokolomonooopoqorosotouovowoxoyozpapbpcpdpepfpgphpipjpkplpmpnpopppqprpsptpupvpwpxpypzqaqbqcqdqeqfqgqhqiqjqkqlqmqnqoqpqqqrqsqtquqvqwqxqyqzrarbrcrdrerfrgrhrirjrkrlrmrnrorprqrrrsrtrurvrwrxryrzsasbscsdsesfsgshsisjskslsmsnsospsqsrssstsusvswsxsysztatbtctdtetftgthtitjtktltmtntotptqtrtstttutvtwtxtytzuaubucudueufuguhuiujukulumunuoupuqurusutuuuvuwuxuyuzvavbvcvdvevfvgvhvivjvkvlvmvnvovpvqvrvsvtvuvvvwvxvyvzwawbwcwdwewfwgwhwiwjwkwlwmwnwowpwqwrwswtwuwvwwwxwywzxaxbxcxdxexfxgxhxixjxkxlxmxnxoxpxqxrxsxtxuxvxwxxxyxzyaybycydyeyfygyhyiyjykylymynyoypyqyrysytyuyvywyxyyyz

I don't know why,can someone help me out ?

Comment: Wow, it's like excel a-z, then aa-az ...

Comment: $i is a string and the i++ could be concatenating them

Comment: What is it that you actually want it to print out? The alphabet?

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig You got it dude :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increment behavior on strings - PHP easter egg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885440/increment-behavior-on-strings-php-easter-egg)

Comment: @DucAnh Easiest way would be `echo 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';`. But aside from that...you can't use characters the same way you can use numbers. Doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at what [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) says about incrementing characters:

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations
>   on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a =
>   'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into
>   '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that
>   character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so
>   only plain ASCII characters (a-z and A-Z) are supported.
>   Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the
>   original string is unchanged.

Comment: Tks man! So $i="z" then $i++ will give the result $i="aa" right ?
And "z" < "aa",that seem kind of weird isnt it ? @@

Comment: Yeah. You can try to abort the loop when $i == 'z', for example. Using a `break`.

Comment: @DucAnh the comparison used for "z" < "aa" is a lexical one, like in "bar" < "car" < "case". It's not weird, just not the one you expect

Comment: Yeah, it is not weird. It is logically correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to print a-z then PHP's [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function can be useful

http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

```
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $letter) {
    echo $letter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this:

```
for($i="a"; $i != "aa"; $i++)
{
  echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening, or why you'd do it like this.. But if you just want an array (?) with all the characters a-z, try:

$myArray = range('a', 'z');

Answer (score 0):

`"aa" <= "z"` returns `true` because of the lexical comparison (which is not the comparison you're expecting), so your loop continues until `"za"`.

As mentioned in other answers, use `range('a', 'z')` or `for($i="a"; $i != "aa"; $i++)`

Answer (score 0):

In for-loop from 2nd time increment works first and then it check condition so here at the last when $i="Z", ($i<="z") check after ($i++) at that time when it increase its value, $i become "z" to "aa" which is again smaller than "z" so the looping remain continue up to "yz".