# A confision of increment operator

Tags: php

```
$a = 'z99';
var_dump(++$a);
```

Above code will output `aa00`.I'm very confused about this output. Can somebody help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885440/increment-behavior-on-strings-php-easter-egg#8885486

Comment: You are incrementing string order  z99, aa00, aa01 etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's because PHP follows Perl's convention.

You can find more information on http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

So because this is a string the 99 goes to 00 -> next increment and the Z goes to AA. If you would have done it with Y99 it would have been Z00.

```
$s = 'W';
for ($n=0; $n<6; $n++) {
    echo ++$s . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Returns:

X
Y
Z
AA
AB
AC

Note that decrementing strings won't work in PHP.

```
$s = 'W';
for ($n=0; $n<6; $n++) {
    echo --$s . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Returns:
W W W W W W